# Facebook SDK Android, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider

Tags: android, facebook

Has anyone encountered this error before with Facebook SDK for Android?

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file "/data/app/com.hellogold.app.dev-2/base.apk"]

Comment: Is this your first time setup? or you are getting this error after making changes to SDK?

Comment: This is post setup, and I didn't have problems with the SDK prior to this.

Comment: My bad @MohammedAtif, it is my first install.

Comment: Did you add the provider details in your manifest file?

Comment: Do you mean the meta data? Like this? <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
If yes, I added this. If no, you need to let me now what else to add, because their instructions didn't include any provider details section

Comment: I am not using FB image uploads so I won't need the provider, or do I?

Comment: Are you using multidex ?

Comment: @Debdeep yes, we are using multidex

Comment: I think i need to declare it in the multidex config file, but even after that the file can't be found.

Comment: It's definitely a multidex issue, but need more digging as to why the multidex configuration is not working

Comment: I figured out that I need to create a multidexkeepfile, and I have input this as the path to the internal facebook class com/facebook/internal/FacebookInitProvider.class, it doesn't seem to be the right path because the class is still unfound, if any of you guys know this it would be great.

Comment: kaizenx, did you solve this?

Comment: @EthanFischer yeap I did, you need help?

Comment: I do. Could you post an answer below explaining what you did with multidex to get it working? Or point to some resources that helped you? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @EthanFischer i actually got the answer from the a post that a groupon engineer did a while back.
I can't remember the link, but I can post my implementation of his fix here.

I don't understand why the official method by Google does not work, maybe needs a higher API level than I want to assign for my app.

Comment: @kaizenx just include  multiDexEnabled true and sync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixed my multidex issues for me. I got them from a group on engineer's blog post, thought I can't remember the original link, if anyone can find it, please link it in the comments and I will edit my answer to reflect that I got my solution from his blog post.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    task "fix${variant.name.capitalize()}MainDexClassList" << {
        logger.info "Fixing main dex keep file for $variant.name"
        File keepFile = new File("$buildDir/intermediates/multi-dex/$variant.buildType.name/maindexlist.txt")
        keepFile.withWriterAppend { w ->
            // Get a reader for the input file
            w.append('\n')
            new File("${projectDir}/multidex.keep").withReader { r ->
                // And write data from the input into the output
                w << r << '\n'
            }
            logger.info "Updated main dex keep file for ${keepFile.getAbsolutePath()}\n$keepFile.text"
        }
    }
}
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (task.name == "create${variant.name.capitalize()}MainDexClassList") {
            task.finalizedBy "fix${variant.name.capitalize()}MainDexClassList"
        }
    }
}
```

So the above worked for

`compileSdkVersion 25
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 25
multiDexEnabled true`

I declared it in the app's gradle and not the main gradle.

Comment: Can you clarify where you put the first block of code?

Comment: @EthanFischer after you declare the repositories and apply plugins

Answer (score 1):

I've got same problem and was because I call MultiDex.install in App.onCreate, moving to App.attachBaseContext() solved the problem. Because provides installing starts before App.onCreate.